# Why is there an upper limit to the photon energy that can be observed in the discrete emission spectrum of the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, hydrogen

I think it must have to do with the fact that an incident photon with a sufficiently high energy will ionize the hydrogen atom (i.e. the electron will be ejected). Therefore it won't show in the emission spectrum. Is this correct?

Comment: Kind of, but backwards. The well is only so deep, so an electron dropping from right at the continuum down to the 1s state can only release 13.6eV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest an e- can get to nucleus is the 1st, it can't get closer and so can't get to lower E. If an e- is beyond the influence of the nucleus and falls to 1s it can't fall any further  (drop in E any more ). This represents the largest E emission.  Once an e- is beyond the influence of the nucleus it doesn't matter how much further it goes it is still beyond its influence and hence the energy of the transition doesn't increase

Comment: Can you please at least spell out stuff fully?

Comment: The max E emission is the energy an e- releases upon falling to the 1s  from a distance so far away from the nucleus that nucleus has no hold. If an e- is further away makes no difference.  Can't make it simpler than that.  If you don't understand please be more specific about what you don't get